# Drupal 7 installation

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

Everytime i try to setup a drupal 7 installation throught that link: http://127.0.0.1:8080/drupal/install.php?profile=standard it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1/drupal/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en without including the port number which give me ressource not found and when i add the port manually to the link it works. How to fix the port number with the link throught redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your /sites/default/settings.php file. You should have the correct DB and password specified there.

Drupal checks a number of spots for valid settings.php files.